# I can't connect internet using wireless network

Tags: wireless, zte

I have tried to connect to internet using reliance netconnect+ (manufactured by ZTE).
I am unable to install it, even from the CD given by the manufacturer.

My os is ubuntu 12.04 lts.

Can you help with any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

On he top left of the Panel click on the Network manager widget and open the Edit connections or search for network connections in the unity launcher.

[image]

In the Network manger select Mobile broadband tab and select

[image]

Click on add

[image]

Select device and continue ahead.They will ask your Provider and your dial number along with username and password .Once you have done this you can connect to it from the widget in top left

**Method 2**

You need to install two software packages to make the internet connectivity work consistently without breaking. They are wvdial and gnome-ppp (The front-end tool to configure wvdial).

1) Install wvdial package

Open terminal,(alt+ctrl+t) and type the following command

`sudo apt-get install wvdial`

2) Install gnome-ppp

`sudo apt-get install gnome-ppp`

3) Open gnome-ppp from the terminal.

`sudo gnome-ppp`

4)You have to enter your reliance 10-digit mobile number in the Username & your password. Select #777(whichever dialup you usualy use) if you are a Reliance Netconnect Broadband+ user. Then press the Setup button below.

5) In the Setup window below, click the “Detect” button to identify the device ID of the USB port in which you have inserted your USB modem. The tool would automatically detect the Device, Type  and Speed of your USB modem. Once it has deteced, please the “Close” button below.

Once this is done click on Connect!!!